# Access caller arguments from callback

Tags: node.js

I have this:

```
var parseFile = function(err, data) {
 // I need to access 'myFile'
};
fs.readFile(myFile, 'utf8', parseFile);
```

How can I access `'myFile'` within the callback declared elsewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function parseFile(myFile) {
  return function (err, data) {
    // its a closure bound variable! yay.
  }
}

fs.readFile(myFile, "utf8", parseFile(myFile))
```

Comment: A level of indirection seems to almost always work :)